# Javascript file not working when open html on browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a file in html with linked css and javascript files. The html is supposed to be like an address book where it is possible to add a contact, search a contact by name and show all the contacts there are in the book. I got the code from a codepen page but when I try to use it in my file it doesn't work and I don't know why. Under is the codepen file with the original code and my code will be in the snippet.

https://codepen.io/ritaD86/pen/MyOdQr

```js
persons = [
    person = {
      firstName: "Maria",
      lastName: "Fernanda",
      age: "mf@desk.com",
      phone: "917697967"
    },
  ];
  
  document.getElementById('search_button').addEventListener('click', searchPerson);
  document.getElementById('add_button').addEventListener('click', addPerson);
  document.getElementById('show_all').addEventListener('click', showAllPersons);

  function searchPerson() {
    var input = document.getElementById("search").value.toLowerCase();
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
  
    for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
  
      if (input === persons[i].firstName.toLowerCase() || input === persons[i].lastName.toLowerCase()) {
        result.innerHTML = '<h4>I found this:</h4>' + persons[i].firstName + ' ' +
          persons[i].lastName + ' </br>' + persons[i].age + ' </br>' + persons[i].phone;
        return persons[i];
  
      } else if (!isNaN(input)) {
        result.innerHTML = 'Tem de inserir um nome';
      } else {
        result.innerHTML = 'Nenhum contacto encontrado';
      }
    }
  }
  
  function Person(first, last, age, phone) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.phone = phone;
  }
  
  function titleCase(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }
  
  function addPerson() {
    var firstName = titleCase(document.getElementById("name").value);
    var lastName = titleCase(document.getElementById("lastname").value);
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  
    var newPerson = new Person(firstName, lastName, age, phone);
    persons.push(newPerson);
  
    if (newPerson.firstName != undefined) {
      alert(newPerson.firstName + ' added');
    } else {
      alert('No person added');
    }
    
    showAllPersons();
  }
  
  function showAllPersons() {
    var i;
    var l;
    var showButton = document.getElementById('show_all');
    var list = document.getElementById('all_list');
    
    while (list.firstChild) {
      list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
    }
    
    
    for (var l = 0; l < persons.length; l++) {
      var node = document.createElement("LI");
      list.appendChild(node);
      node.innerHTML =
        '<p><b>Nome Completo:</b> ' + persons[l].firstName +' ' + persons[l].lastName + '</p>' +
        '<p><b>Email:</b> ' + persons[l].age + '</p>' +
        '<p><b>Telemovel:</b> ' + persons[l].phone + '</p>'
  
      for (var key in person) {
        var value = person[key];
      }
    }
    showButton.disabled = true;
  }
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

form {
  padding: 20px 0 40px;
}
form .field {
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
form .field label {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.3576520234%;
  width: 40.291369653%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
form .field label:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
form .field input {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.3576520234%;
  width: 57.3509783236%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
form .field input:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.search_person {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.3576520234%;
  width: 48.8211739883%;
}
.search_person:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.add_person {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.3576520234%;
  width: 48.8211739883%;
}
.add_person:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.all_persons {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.3576520234%;
  width: 31.7615653177%;
  margin-left: 34.1192173411%;
}
.all_persons:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.all_persons #all_list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.all_persons #all_list li {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Desk+ - Grupo 36</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ab.css">
        <script src="ab.js"></script>
        </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Contactos</h1>
    
    <div class="all_persons">
      <button id="show_all" type="button">Mostrar todos</button>
      <ul id="all_list">
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="search_person">
      <h3>Insira um nome</h3>
      <input type="text" id="search">
      <button id="search_button" type="button">Procurar</button>
      <p id="result"></p>
    </div>
  
   <div class="add_person">
     <h3>Adicionar contacto</h3>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="field">
          <label for="firstname">Primeiro Nome: </label>
          <input type="text" id="name">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label for="lastname">Último Nome: </label>
          <input type="text" id="lastname">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label for="age">Email: </label>
          <input type="text" id="age">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
          <input type="number" id="phone">
        </div>
        <button id="add_button" type="button">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Apparently the code works in the snippet but when i create the html page on my browser it doesn't work so can you help me out?

Comment: When running the script, the HTML elements haven't loaded. Try placing the script tag last in the page.

Comment: In the end of the body then? Or between `</body>` and `</html>`

Comment: Put it in the middle of `</body>` and `</html>` and worked. Thanks man

Comment: This happens because your script runs before the elements are created. You should load your script just before you close the body tag (not after) or add an event listener to init your script after DOM is ready.

Comment: you can also use the JQuery function $( document ).ready() which waits until your document is loaded then executes your javascript code : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, moving your script towards the end of the `body` tag will resolve your issue, however, a better approach will be to enclose the immediately called part (not the function definition) of your script inside a `load` event listener. The event will be fired only after all elements in your page is loaded regardless of the position where you put your script.

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    console.log('page is fully loaded');
});
```

Your script should look like below.

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    document.getElementById('search_button').addEventListener('click', searchPerson);
    document.getElementById('add_button').addEventListener('click', addPerson);
    document.getElementById('show_all').addEventListener('click', showAllPersons);
});
```